# Неудачная попытка инициализировать массив из структуры

Tags: c, массивы, структуры, инициализация

Я хочу сделать структуру, в которой будет целочисленный массив из 10 элементов. При попытке инициализировать массив из структуры мне компилятор пишет ошибку **expected expression before '{' token**. Пишу на Си, вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    struct array {
        int i[10];
    } arr;

    arr.i = { 4, 2, 1 };

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    printf("%d", arr.i[2]);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Почему вылазит эта ошибка? Как её можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это -

```
arr.i = { 4, 2, 1 };
```

**не** *инициализация*, а попытка *присваивания*. Инициализация - вот:

```
struct array {
    int i[10];
} arr = { 4, 2, 1 };
```

Попробуйте так...